# Angular Two dependent components, change in second must change the first

Tags: angular, dependencies, components, notify

A label and a table with multiple rows on the same page. Label needs to be synced with table.

**Component 1**

Total of analyses = 2

**Component 2 (a table)**

filterBy: [none]

1. Sample from analysis 1
2. Sample from analysis 1
3. Sample from analysis 2

You see component 1 depends on 2. Problem is the table in Component 2 has a filter input field. When you filter and press *Enter* it does an API call. The list returned might be different because from another part of our app a new analyses have been added.

---

**Component 1**

Total of analyses = 2 (***Problem***: same value after filter call. Someone from another page added analyses.)

**Component 2 (a table)**

filterBy: [1,2,3]

1. Sample from analysis 1
2. Sample from analysis 1
3. Sample from analysis 2
4. Sample from analysis 3
5. Sample from analysis 3

From another screen analyses 2,3,4 were added. Correct Total should be 4, not 2. But filter API only updated the table. (Sample from analysis 4 did not match filter).

---

**(!!)** You cannot compute or deduce the Total from the table. So you cannot update using Output events. Because filter does not return all values.

*My thoughts on solutions*

I have thought to use one GET call for label and for table. One call retrieves the filtered table and the total analyses at once, solving the sync problem. But the label and table need to be reusable, be two separate components.

So, I need two components and one call (to solve sync problem).
Thusly, I made a *parent* component for that one GET call and then send using Input() to Component 1 the label data and to Component 2 the table data.

**Question**
I had a big brainstorm thinking also about using SignalR and any other solution. This looks like a very common scenario, so I want to ask. What solution would you use?

**Edited example to highlight impossibility to compute label data from table data.**

Comment: Just to confirm, does your components has a parent child relationship? or are you calling both the components in any other components, I want to understand the structure so that I can provide you the correct solution

Comment: I am calling both of the components in any other components. The Parent X was just my idea to solve.
Please note: I cannot compute the label value from the table. I wrote a remark, but seeing the answers its better to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your components set up in a parent child fashion with app-selectors, you can use an output event from component 2 to tell component 1 about the new total.

EG:

```
<component1>
    <component2 (totalChange)="totalChanged($event)"></component2>
</component1>
```

In the child component you need to declare an output event emitter:

```
 @Output()
  totalChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Then after your api call in component 2, when you get new data, emit the new total value:

```
// make API call and get new data
// emit event with new total of data
this.totalChanged.emit(newTotal);
```

Then in component1 you can add a function called 'totalChanged':

```
public totalChanged(total: number){
    this.total = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two cases:

**parent-child relationship**

if `component-1` is parent and `component-2` is its child, then you can use `Outupt` decorator to define an `EventEmitter` which will be emitted once filter function is called, results are fetched and sum is calculated.

`@Output() filterUsed = new EventEmitter<number>();`

```
filter(input) {
   ....
   this.sum = ....;
   this.filterUsed.emit(this.sum);
}
```

then in the parent `component-1` use an `Event-Binding` in the tag of the `component-2`

`<app-component-2 (filterUsed)="getNewSum($event)"></app-component-2>`

and inside `getNewSum(sum)` function, update the value of the sum in the parent component;

**not-related components**

if `component-1` and `component-2` are not related, then you can add a middleware **service** that will be injected in both components.

this service must contain an **observable** that will be used by `component-2` (next) to carry a new value of sum for the `component-1` (subscribe).